# Generate excel sheet using php with few non editable cells

Tags: php, excel

I want to generate excelsheet using php so which method or code is preferable to use to generate dynamic excelsheet?  Please check a screenshot image for more idea what I am facing issue.! 
[screenshot of required excel sheet format](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wjwjz2019erk07y/excel_generate_issue.png)
Please, anyone can help me to sort out these issue? Thanks in advance.

I am using below code example.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$pre."customers");
    if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
    $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
    $headers = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
    {
        $headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i);
        mysql_field_name($result , $i);
    }

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    if ($fp && $result)
    {
            header('Content-Type: text/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export1.csv"');
            header('Pragma: no-cache');
            header('Expires: 0');
            fputcsv($fp, $headers);

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
            {
                 fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
            }

            die;
     }
```

But I don't that I can lock any cell into this excel sheet. So which php method or class are suitable to generate excelsheet for my purpose to use?

Comment: Stackoverflow recommends specific questions. Place some code and explain what is unexpected you are getting then someone may try to help.

Comment: Can be above description enough to answer by someone?

Comment: Thats better. Also consider adding tags such as JQuery and PHP. This way may help your question to get more attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function get_excel($err = array())
 {

     // Clear any previous output
ob_end_clean();
// I assume you already have your $result
$search = ($this->uri->segment(2))?$this->uri->segment(2):'key';
$result=mysql_query("select * from job");
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);


// Fetch MySQL result headers
$headers = array();
//$headers[] = "serial no";
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {


    $headers[] = strtoupper(mysql_field_name($result , $i));
}


// Filename with current date
$current_date = date("y/m/d");
$filename = "MyFileName" . $current_date . ".csv";

// Open php output stream and write headers
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');

    // Write mysql headers to csv
    fputcsv($fp, $headers);
    //$row_tally = 0;
    // Write mysql rows to csv
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
   // $row_tally = $row_tally + 1;
    //echo $row_tally.",";
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
    }
    die;
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want more out of CSV than possible. Are you aware of the import functions in excel? You can easily set up the document to recieve only the dynamic content as CSV (lower part) from your own php-service etc...

My version of Excel is danish but its under det data-tab and something like "from internet" :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me try another solution for this issue. Because I can't able to explain what I need exactly. Thanks again.